# Implement JailBroken Protection for the iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I detect that an SDK app is running on a jailbroken phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413242/how-do-i-detect-that-an-sdk-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone)

My Applications don't have JailBroken Protections features implemented.

This often helps the attackers who would use the Jailborken device to analyse and exploit the vulnerabilities. 
How can I implement JailBroken protection that prevents applications running on the JailBroken device ?

Comment: This is only to check if "Cydia" is installed. But in general I need to know how is it possible to prevent.

Comment: As you can see from the linked answers, you try to detect if the phone is jailbroken by one of various means. If you detect it, you have can deal with it, e.g. Show an alert or just close the app. But that doesn't come out of the box.

Comment: As Holger say's once you know it's jailbroken, it's up to you  to handle it. Note that it is more then Cydia, also look for folders outside your sandbox like bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342571/no-jailbreak-detection), it has the code you need.

You can also see if you can fork a process (This will only work on jailbroken phones)

And one [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12085504/detect-jailbroken-device).
And [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413242/how-do-i-detect-that-an-sdk-app-is-running-on-a-jailbroken-phone).